# Are lines in arbitrary normed vector spaces closed?

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

Let $(V, \| \cdot \|)$ be a normed (real) vector space. Given two vectors $a$ and $d$ (with $d$ not the zero vector), is the line
$
L = \{a + td: t \in \mathbb{R}\}
$
through $a$ in direction $d$ necessarily a closed set?

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, this seems easy (for instance by showing that the line is polyhedral), but my different proofs all seem to rely on its finite-dimensionality. Making me suspect that the answer in general is probably no$\ldots$

Answer (score 1):

Take any convergent sequence $(x_n)$of points on this line. Since each $x_n$ is on this line  there is a sequence $(t_n)$ such that $x_n=a+t_nd$ where $0 \le t_n \le 1.$ Show that limit of $x_n$ is also on this line. Then you will have the closedness.

Answer (score 0):

To show a set is closed, you just have to take an arbitrary point not in that set and find an open neighborhood of that point which does not intersect your set.  So, is there a point not on the line but such that every open neighborhood of the point meets the line?  If so, what point?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried to figure it out that way, but even in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that wasn't all that easy and my polyhedral proof in the end was much shorter. And for general normed vector spaces, I just don't see how to do this.

Comment: It wasn't easy to show that the distance from a point to a line in $\mathbb{R}^n$ wasn't zero unless the point was on the line?

Comment: The translation to the general case was difficult: take a point not on the line. The set of distances to points on the line is nonempty and bounded from below by zero, so it has an infimum. If the infimum is strictly positive, fine: construct a ball around the off-line point with smaller radius. But what if the infimum happens to be zero?

Comment: That would make the line _not_ closed; but can that scenario happen?